# Sending Private Message ( Socket.IO )

Tags: socket.io

In many Posts or Articles.I often saw something like that.

```
Client-Side :

 socket.emit("shhh!Secrets", {
  To : "AlexId",
  Message : "Hello World!"
 })
```

```
Server-Side: 

 socket.on("shhh!Secrets", (Send) => {
  io.in(Send.TO).emit("SO...Secrets", Send.Message)
 })
```

Whatever it is `socketId` , Specific user `socketObj` or `room` base .

What If I change Client Source code and change with others `room` or `socketId` then my crazy message will saved to others chat timeline...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Method**

Socket.IO is stateful. So this Smart Socket will not forget who you are in every event call.

lets say user want to join  *room001*  
So when Joining a socket to a specific Room,Save `RoomId` To `socket.roomId = "room001"`

Then use `io.in(socket.roomId).emit("SO...Secrets", "message")`

**Second Method**

Never give a change a client directly send message to specific room.

```
Server-Side: 
  
 socket.on("shhh!Secrets", (Send) => {
  // Send message only if the user already joined to this Room
  if (Send instanceof Object && socket.rooms[Send.TO] === Send.TO) 
    io.in(Send.TO).emit("SO...Secrets", Send.Message);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed, of course you can change your client code, but you need to know real userId (AlexId in your example), and it is usually uuid, that is not easy to get... So there is very low chance to do that.

By the way, usually in articles use very simple examples and do not mention security aspects, so be careful with it!

Comment: I use mongo dB default _id for room. So If I increase last number then.It would be others chat room.

Comment: As I told earlier, it is potential vulnerability. You need to check access rights for user and room for writing...